# yesterday a lot of our address searches started "Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ZERO_RESULTS"

Tags: api, dictionary, geocode

"Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ZERO_RESULTS"

using google geocode api, non-premium, very low traffic, some addresses work

issue is somehow localized to accessing from our servers, clients report no problems.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the solution may have been to simply press F5 on each of our servers and local environment after returning a 'no_result' response.

local, dev, staging and production servers all had the same issue for over 12 hours, then by refreshing (F5) using any browser (chrome on local, FF on dev and IE on others) just once on each server solved the problem.

Issue cannot be recreated, so magically it has been resolved.